Getting first occurrence of a specific information in the genealogy tree and then stopping
I have the following dataset which reassembles a genealogy tree.



ancestor
parent
level
child
hair color
tree




Tony

1

Brown
Tony


Tony
Tony
2
Mary
Brown
Tony - Mary


Tony
Tony
2
John
Black
Tony - John


Tony
Mary
3
Katy
Brown
Tony - Mary - Katy


Tony
Mary
3
Jeff
Black
Tony - Mary - Jeff


Tony
John
3
Mike
Brown
Tony - John - Mike


Tony
John
3
Evan
Brown
Tony - John - Evan


Tony
Katy
4
Luca
Brown
Tony - Mary - Katy - Luca


Tony
Katy
4
Isla
Black
Tony - Mary - Jeff - Isla


Tony
Evan
4
Finn
Black
Tony - John - Evan - Finn



I would like to search though each family line, starting from ancestor Tony and return first child with Black hair color.

So starting with Tony (level 1), as he has no Black hair, I would step into the tree.
Moving on to his kids, Mary and John (level 2), we can see Mary's hair is Brown, so we continue in her line, but John's hair is Black so I would stop there, even though Finn from his line has Black hair too.
Moving back to Mary's line, we go to Katy and Jeff (level 3). As we can see Katy has Brown hair so we move forward, but Jeff's hair is Black so we stop there.
Then Katy's child Luca has Brown hair so we stop there as well. The resulting dataset would look like this (Finn is excluded as we stop looking after John):




ancestor
parent
level
child
hair color
tree




Tony
Tony
2
John
Black
Tony - John


Tony
Mary
3
Jeff
Black
Tony - Mary - Jeff


Tony
Katy
4
Isla
Black
Tony - Mary - Jeff - Isla




To achieve this, I tried approach using not in and is like to create a key consisting of ancestor, parent and level (for Black hair color) and exclude them from the dataset, but it didn't work (I could not combine both in the same subquery).
I'd appreciate any other ideas how to tackle this.

Edit: Thank you for the answer MT0, that was very helpful!
To exercise this example more, I added two new columns, ancestor_eye_color and child_eye_color.
First column has same value for all members of the tree for a given ancestor (top level), whereas each child has it's own eye color. The condition would be to make sure, we only output rows where child eye color is different from ancertor's. So that with above example, Jeff would no longer be returned (as he has the same eye color as ancestor), but instead Finn would be in the output.
I tried using PRIOR with this condition but it did not worked as expected. Any ideas how to improve it?
Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/6J8Y0YyQ

You can use a hierarchical query:
SELECT parent,
       child,
       hair_color,
       SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(child, ' - '), 4) AS tree
FROM   table_name
WHERE  hair_color = 'Black'
START WITH parent IS NULL
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR child = parent
AND    PRIOR hair_color <> 'Black';

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (parent, child, hair_color) AS
SELECT NULL,   'Tony', 'Brown' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tony', 'Mary', 'Brown' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tony', 'John', 'Black' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mary', 'Katy', 'Brown' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mary', 'Jeff', 'Black' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', 'Mike', 'Brown' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', 'Evan', 'Brown' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Katy', 'Luca', 'Brown' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Katy', 'Isla', 'Black' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Evan', 'Finn', 'Black' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



PARENT
CHILD
HAIR_COLOR
TREE




Tony
John
Black
Tony - John


Mary
Jeff
Black
Tony - Mary - Jeff


Katy
Isla
Black
Tony - Mary - Katy - Isla



fiddle

Thank you @MT0. That was very helpful. I wanted to exercise more using this example by adding additional columns and condition, but I cannot make it work. Would you mind taking a look at my edited post and fiddle? Thanks in advance!

@ohh In general, if you have a different question you should ask a new question rather than changing your existing question. However, fiddle might answer your question. (Also, if the table represents a person then you only want to store properties relating to that person in the table and not properties of a different person so the ancestors' eye colour should not be stored but you can derive it through the hierarchy)
